# ListView with moving header?

Tags: android

I want to create listview with header which move with listviews scrolling. I tried it :

```
ViewGroup listviewheader = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_header , list1,false);
list1.addHeaderView(listviewheader);
```

But it only appears when user rise to top of the listview. I want that when user rise a little bit (everywhere in listview) then the header appear in top. How can i do it?

Comment: I would prefer a fixed header (outside the ListView). So, it would be always visible.

Comment: Thank you. But i don't want that it can seem always. I want that when user scroll down , it disappear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://github.com/felipecsl/QuickReturn

-- Quite easy and useful implementation

Answer (score 1):

Check this library: https://github.com/ManuelPeinado/QuickReturnHeader

"A ListView/ScrollView header that hides when scrolling down and reappears immediately when scrolling up, regardless of how far down the list we've gone. Like the one from the Google Keep app."